# Proper subgroups of $p$-groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group, $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ two proper subgroups of $G$. Write $C_{H_{1}}$ (resp. $C_{H_{2}}$) for the subgroup of $G$ generated by all the of the conjugacy class of $H_{1}$ (resp. $H_{2}$). Suppose that $H_{1} \subset H_{2}$ and $H_{1} \neq H_{2}$.

My question is as follows: dose $C_{H_{1}} \neq C_{H_{2}}$?

Comment: Take $H$ to be a subgroup such that $H\neq C_H$. Then take $H_1=H$ and $H_2=C_H$.

Comment: No, it can happen that they are equal. Consider $G$ the dihedral group of order $8$. Let $H_{1} = \langle t \rangle$, where $t$ is  non-central involution, and $H_{2}$ to be a Klein $4$-group containing $t$. Then in this case $C_{H_{1}} = C_{H_{2}} = H_{2}$.

Comment: My example special case of Ehud's construcion ( which appeared while I was writing). In any case, this is probably not a research level question.

Comment: $C_H$ is better known as the "normal subgroup generated by $H$"

Answer (score 0):

(Note that $C_H$ is better known as the "normal subgroup generated by $H$", or sometimes "normal closure of $H$")

As mentioned by several people, you always have $H\subset C_H$ and $C_H=C_{C_H}$. So taking $H_1=H$ and $H_2=C_H$ gives a counterexample as soon as $H$ is not a normal subgroup.